# Powershell script writes lines of data to excel cell, but too many lines

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a powershell script that will collect data, actually file paths for anywhere from 3 - 40 different paths.  I have that script populate those file paths into a single cell in an excel template.  The problem is that when there a too many file paths, you cannot see them all without "double clicking" in the cell.  Is there a way to create a double column in excel (using the ps script) or another way to have all those lines of data in the single cell and visible?  I would post the script, but it's on another computer that is not connected to the internet.

Currently, I have each file path write to a new line within the cell for readability.  And I cannot change the template.

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Excel has its [limitations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) for what it can store in one cell and the maximum row height it can display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `autofit`.

Example:

```
$sheet.columns.autofit()
```

Comment: thanks.  I will try this, but I am not sure this will work.  I think at times, there are more lines of data than the cell will allow..as in the cell can only be made so big.